# Iterating outside a java array, why is this happening?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am relatively new to coding and I am starting a  review of leetcode, and floundered on a question...looking at the 3ms-runtime solution leetcode supplied I am confused about the function of the 4th line in method findDisappearedNumbers.

My assumption is that for the 0 index running 'arr[nums[i] - 1]++' would assign 4 to arr[0], but it assigns 1. Can someone help me understand what is happening?

The result of running this code is: [1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FindAllNumbersDisappearedInAnArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1};
        /*System.out.println(findDisappearedNumbers(arr));*/
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findDisappearedNumbers(arr))); //user added for examing code
    }

    public static int[] /*List<Integer>*/ findDisappearedNumbers(int[] nums) { //int[] was user added for examing code
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] arr = new int[nums.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            arr[nums[i] - 1]++; //What is happening here?
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == 0) {
                list.add(i+1);
            }
        }
        /*return list;*/
        return arr; //user added for examing code
    }
}
```

(The question was:

Given an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once.

Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this array.

Could you do it without extra space and in O(n) runtime? You may assume the returned list does not count as extra space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `arr[nums[i] - 1]++;`, `nums[i] - 1` determines the index of a value in `arr[]`, not the value which should be wirtten into it. Than the found value is incremented by one, because of `++`.

Knowing that the default value of an int is 0, so when `arr[]` is initialized it contains only zeros, we can see, that after the first iteration of the first for loop `arr[]` is [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]. We see a 1 on the 4.th (starting from 1) position of `arr[]`, which means that one 4 has been found in `nums[]`.

If you add `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)` after the first for loop you will see following output: [1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]. According to the logic described above, it means, that `nums[]` contains one 1, two 2s, two 3s, one 4, **no 5**, **no 6**, one 7 and one 8.